# How to zip files in a specific date range

Tags: command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip

I'm looking for a way to zip files in a specific date range using a script.

For example I would need something that zips files in a specified folder with date modified being 2020.

I tried the solution suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567022/using-7zip-to-archive-file-by-year

Full code of the .bat file I'm trying to use:

```
@echo off

set 7z=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
if not exist %7z% set /p 7z="Path to 7-zip executable? "

set /p year="What year do you wish to archive? "

set /p dir="What is the path of the files you wish to archive? "

mkdir "%year%"

rem output of dir is date time am/pm size filename
rem filename = 5th + additional tokens
for /f "tokens=5*" %%I in ('dir "%dir%" ^| find "/%year%"') do move "%dir%\%%I %%J" "%year%"

%7z% a -tzip "%dir%\%year%.zip" "%year%" -mx5

set /p I="I'm about to delete the %year% folder.  Hit Ctrl-C if this is a bad idea, or hit Enter to continue."
rmdir /q /s "%year%"

echo Done.
```

But I'm getting this error message when I try to run the batch script:

> 'zdiryearyear" -mx5' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

Any other suggestions on how this could be accomplished are most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD syntax uses `%n` for referencing arguments, like `echo %1 %2`. For this reason, you should **not** use variable names that start with a number, like `7z`. You can kind of see the problem if you turn `@echo` on. Example from [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html):

> `SET 1=Hello`
>
> You might expect that to create the variable %1%, but in a batch file it will Fail.
>
> Even if the script was called without passing any parameter %1, the parameters take precedence, so %1% is evaluated as %1 plus an extra % at the end. Remember the command line is parsed left to right only once, so the %1 is evaluated **before** the second % is even read.

Note that this only applies in bat files, since they can get called with arguments